# Kivy: Cargar un texto de un fichero en un label

Tags: python, programación-móvil, kivy

Quiero cargar un texto de un fichero en un label. 
Mi código en python es:

```
# config
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def showtext(self):
        with open("Prueba.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            #self.ids['label1'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self): 
        return True
    def on_resume(self): 
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'): 
    myApp().run()
```

El archivo design.kv es:

```
<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: label1
            text: root.showtext()
```

Me da un error: *ValueError: None is not allowed for Label.text*

Parece que ya que tengo definida la función `showtext` como `def showtext(self)` he de poner algo donde va "self" en el archivo design.kv, entonces pongo "label1" quedándome el archivo design.kv así:

```
<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: label1
            text: root.showtext(label1)
```

Entonces me dá el siguiente error:
*TypeError: showtext() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given*

No lo entiendo, dice que le he dado dos argumentos, cuando solo le he dado uno, label1.
¿Podría decirme alguien que he de poner o cambiar para cargar texto de un txt en label?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que merece la pena el esfuerzo invertido en tratar esta serie de preguntas básicas en Kivy. Hay videotutoriales, en inglés, pero no veo ninguno que trate los aspectos más básicos planteados en las preguntas que estoy haciendo. Muchas gracias a todos los que se están involucrando en contestar estas preguntas ya que creo que contribuyen  en hacer de Kivy un framework más accesible a todo el mundo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema te lo dice el propio error, estas intentando pasar `None` como texto para el `Label`. La duda es, ¿de donde viene el `None`?

En tu archivo .kv defines que el texto es la función `showtext`, entoces se llama al método para obtener el texto. El problema es que el método `showtext` no retorna nada, si a una función/método en Python no le defines un retorno mediante `return` esta retorna `None` por defecto.

Para que esta forma que intentas funcione debes hacer que el método retorne el texto:

```
def showtext(self):
    with open("Prueba.txt","r") as f:
        return(f.read())
```

El primer archivo kv que agregas es el correcto:

```
<MyWidget>:
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: root.showtext()
```

En cuanto a tu duda de porqué dice que le estas pasando dos argumentos cuando le pasas solo uno al hacer `text: root.showtext(label1)`. Esto se debe a que el parámetro `self` se pasa de forma automática, aunque al crear el método hay que definirlo de forma explícita. Es decir, aunque tu llamas haciendo:

```
 root.showtext(label1)
```

Internamente la llamada simbólicamente sería algo como:

```
showtext(self, label1)
```

`self` en realidad es una convención recomendada en los PEP, puede llamarse como queramos, no es una palabra reservada, aunque llamarla `self` hace la vida más fácil a otros que lean nuestro código. En realidad  no es mas que una referencia a la propia instancia de la clase, una referencia a si misma, de ahí lo del nombre 'self'. Indica que ese método o atributo pertenecen a la clase.

Otra opción para hacer lo mismo sería no definir el texto en el .kv y usar el atributo text del label para pasarle el texto desde el propio código Python. La función en este caso puede ser llamada por otro widget, como un botón, o llamarla desde el propio constructor:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


Builder.load_file('design2.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.showtext() #Llamamos al método desde el constructor

    def showtext(self):
        with open("Prueba.txt","r") as f:
            self.ids['Label1'].text = f.read()


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

en este caso el .kv sería simplemente:

```
<MyWidget>:
    Label:
        id: Label1
```